# Is it possible to have a Datasheet view as a Webpart?

Tags: 2010, web-part, datasheet

I am looking for a solution to the above. If it is not possible... is there an alternative to the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, I have it in several locations.

Create your desired datasheet view in the list, go to your web part page and add the list web part and change the view to use the datasheet view.

Comment: I tried it.. But my Datasheet view is always read-only in the webpart. What to do for it?

Comment: Depending what coulmns you have in the view can make it read only. Try removing one at a time to see what columns are triggering it to be read only.

Comment: Have tried it! Works perfectly on SP2010. In WSS it was a pain to make it work!! Thanks @PirateEric